# Pass variables to scriptblock within a scriptblock on remote computer

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am attempting to query a domain controller using `Get-ADComputer` for Active Directory information about a specific computer.  This computer is specified by a variable in a local script.  However, I can't pass a local variable to the scriptblock for `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList` then into the `-Filter{}` block in `Get-ADComputer`.  Below is what I thought would work:

```
$computername = "nicolas"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName DomainController -ScriptBlock {
  Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like "$args[0]"}
} -ArgumentList $computername
```

However, the `$args[0]` variable does not pass through to the internal filter; it passes to the initial scriptblock, but no farther.  It is defined inside of the first scriptblock (I can correctly return its value), but is not defined inside of the `-Filter{}` scriptblock.  How can I pass this variable from my local script, to the remote scriptblock, and into the `-Filter{}`?

I've attempted `$args[]`, `$USING:computername`, but neither seem to let me pass it all the way through.

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate question.

Comment: Have you tried this syntax?  

Invoke-Command -ComputerName DomainController -ScriptBlock {
  Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like "$using:ComputerName"}
}

Comment: @FoxDeploy I have in fact tried that syntax, with no luck.  I'm currently reviewing the suggested question that I may be duplicating for answers.

Comment: try running something like this, to see that your param is getting piped through

Invoke-Command -ComputerName DomainController -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "I am passing through this param $using:ComputerName"} } 

If you see the sentence show up in a way that makes sense, you know you're onto something!

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Thanks for the link; I did not know that it's not possible to "pass expressions as the second operand"; my actual situation was somewhat more complex than the question, but using that information I was able to cast the variable as a string and pass it through.  Thanks.

Comment: @FoxDeploy The problem is caused by the misleading syntax Microsoft chose for the argument of the `-Filter` parameter. Despite what it looks like the argument is actually treated as a string, not a scriptblock.